# Local assets are coming in as a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I can no longer seem to render out local assets on my RN application. The project itself is quite large and is currently being worked by a team of ~10 people. So it's difficult to tell exactly when or where the break happened.

We recently updated RN to v0.58.5 and most of our team's assumption is that the break happened during the more than painful upgrade process.

We have a few components that render out images and all of them check first if a URL is being returned:

`const source = isUrl(icon) ? { uri: icon } : icon;`

Then we pass that into the component and it is handled like so:

`<Image source={source} />`

Urls are working completely fine, but when I put a console.log to read any local assets all we get back is a number.

Sometimes 1. Sometimes 2. Sometimes 13.

My assumption is that the metro bundler is trying to load that number of assets. Coming from a web background mostly, I am sort of unsure how to adjust and configure the metro bundler or which configuration files to show here to help.

The issue occurs with both svg and png files. We are exporting these assets from local packages like:

`export const file = require("./track-info-assets/album-art.png");`

and importing like this:

`import { file } from "@assets-track-info";`

That may be important to note. However, the exact same problem also occurs if the file is local to the component's package.

The issue persists on both Android and iOS. Any help is greatly appreciated.